# How to create a date object from string consisting of Hour, Minute, Date, Month and Year?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I need to convert a string eg: `"6 Aug 2020 23:40"` to a date object which I can then use to convert to ISO.
I am aware of the `Date.parse()` and new `Date()` but could not find for this particular format.

Comment: If you have a date format that the Date object constructor, or any parsing methods, can not understand natively - then you will have to take your input value apart into its components on your own, and then feed them to the constructor in a form it does understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work fine here:

```js
'use strict';
let o = new Date('6 Aug 2020 23:40');
console.log(o);
```